# Cauchy sequences as proof of integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be integrable in every compact set of
$[a,+\infty)$.

Prove that

$\int_a^{+\infty}f(t)dt<\infty\Longleftrightarrow\forall\epsilon>0$

$\exists a_0>a:\forall a_2>a_1>a_0$

$|\int_{a_1}^{a_2}f(t)dt|<\epsilon$

Hello everyone, I'm struggling with this problem.
The strategy I'm thinking of is that since $F(x)= \int_a^{x}f(t)dt$ converges for $x\rightarrow\infty$ this means that for all sequence $x_n\rightarrow\infty$, $F(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, because if it wasn't the integral wouldn't converge.

I feel that the idea is right but I'm not getting anywhere because i find it difficult to put it as a rigorous proof and I don't know how to go on from this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "integrable in every dense set of 
$[a,+\infty)$"? Isn't $[a,+\infty)$ itself such a dense set? Integrable in which sense? Is $\int_a^{+\infty}f(t)dt$ supposed to exist? What is its definition?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I'll explain: I actually meant compact set, my bad; yes the integral is supposed to exist and be in the real field; "integrable" as in Riemann integrable; as to its definition I don't know how to answer you since the exercise was written this way. Let me know if you have any more questions, and thank you :)

Comment: Duplicate: [Proof of Cauchy's Criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546434).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_a^{+\infty} f(t)\; dt$ is an improper integral.  In the context of Riemann integration, the standard way of defining it is
$$ \lim_{b \to +\infty} \int_a^b f(t)\; dt$$
The improper integral converges if and only if this limit exists.  (I don't like writing "the improper integral converges" as $\int_a^{+\infty} f(t)\; dt < \infty$, because what if it diverges to $-\infty$, but presumably that's what is meant here)

Now use the $\varepsilon-N$ definition of limit as $b \to +\infty$.

Comment: sorry what do you mean with the $\epsilon - N$ definition of limit?

Comment: $\lim_{b \to +\infty} F(b) = L$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $|F(b)-L| < \epsilon$ whenever $b > N$.

Comment: Thanks, i'll use this!